# Is there javascript equivalent to R's use of ":" for returning a string of numbers between the numbers on either side of the colon?

Tags: javascript, r, equivalent

I am currently learning javascript, but I come completely from an R background (primarily coded for multivariable statistics). I was wondering if there was some equivalent to R's use of `:` in javascript.

For example, in R Studio, I can simply type `2:6` in order to get a string of numbers from 2 to 6 (ie: R Studio would output `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`).

Currently, I've had to create a whole function that does it, which isn't very efficient, nor would it be convenient when coding for larger projects. Also, if there IS a javascript equivalent, I'm hoping that it would work with functions/functions of objects, and not just integers.

Ex of what I mean: In R, typing `Data2 = table(myData[2:4,(1:ncol(myData)),])` would create a table "Data2" using not ONLY rows 2, 3, 4 of myData, but ALSO use the columns from 1 THROUGH the end of the number of columns in myData. So basically, I'm hoping that it'd be able to use other functions within it.

I really hope that makes sense! If not, please don't hesitate to ask me to clarify!

Comment: `Currently, I've had to create a whole function that does it, which isn't very efficient` I'd bet that's exactly the same thing R does, except that it's built-in rather than being an external function. `nor would it be convenient when coding for larger projects` Write it once, use/import it everywhere you need to, not so hard IMO

Comment: in JS it would be: `Data2 = myData.slice(2,5).map(row => row.slice(1))`. In the several functional frameworks in JS you'll most certainly also find some implementation that does this lazily, without the intermediate Array; In case this ever get's a bottleneck.

Comment: @Thomas this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah, I was thinking about doing that, since I had already written the function, but I use a loop in the function, and I was just thinking about how much time it would take if I was going to implement it across a large amount of data or something! It probably wouldn't be a problem if I had a larger amount of functions in my repertoire, but I'm just starting out and I definitely need to work on shortening/stream-lining my code!